# エクセルVBAからjavaを呼び出す方法

Tags: java, vba, excel, jar

現在、エクセルVBAからjava処理を呼び出したいと考えています。
以下のようなコードを用意したのですが、うまく動きません。

調べるとjarに対して、マニフェストファイルへの記載が必要？とのことなのですが、
ここでは、`jar -xvf Sample.jar`で解凍したマニフェストファイルに `Main-Class: Sample` を記載して、もう一度圧縮すればいいのでしょうか？

圧縮コマンドは `jar -cvfm Sample.jar manifest.mf *.class` を自分のものに置き換えて実行する予定でいます。
どなたかご存知でしょうか？

用意したJavaコード

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl;

public class SqlFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java SqlFormatter <inputFolder> <outputFolder>");
            return;
        }

        String inputFolder = args[0];
        String outputFolder = args[1];

        File folder = new File(inputFolder);
        File[] files = folder.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));

        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                List<String> formattedSqlList = new ArrayList<>();

                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // SQL文を抽出
                        String sql = extractSql(line);

                        if (sql != null && !sql.isEmpty()) {
                            // SQL文をフォーマット
                            String formattedSql = new BasicFormatterImpl().format(sql);
                            formattedSqlList.add(formattedSql);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // 出力ファイル名を生成
                String outputFileName = outputFolder + File.separator + file.getName();

                // 新しいファイルを作成してフォーマットされたSQLを書き込む
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
                    for (String formattedSql : formattedSqlList) {
                        writer.write(formattedSql);
                        writer.newLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // SQL文を抽出するメソッド（正確な実装はコンテキストに依存します）
    private static String extractSql(String line) {
        // 実装を追加してSQLを抽出
        return line;
    }
}
```

VBA内の記述

```
Sub RunJavaProgram()
    Dim javaPath As String
    Dim jarPath As String
    Dim inputFolder As String
    Dim outputFolder As String
    Dim javaCommand As String

    ' Javaの実行可能ファイルのパス（java.exe）を設定
    javaPath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe"  ' あなたのJavaのパスに合わせて設定

    ' 実行するJavaプログラムのJARファイルのパスを設定
    jarPath = "C:\path\to\your\java\program.jar"  ' あなたのJARファイルのパスに合わせて設定

    ' 入力フォルダと出力フォルダのパスを設定
    inputFolder = "C:\path\to\input\folder"
    outputFolder = "C:\path\to\output\folder"

    ' Javaプログラムを実行するコマンドを組み立て
    javaCommand = """" & javaPath & """ -jar """ & jarPath & """ """ & inputFolder & """ """ & outputFolder & """"

    ' コマンドを実行
    Call Shell(javaCommand, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: 「うまく動きません。」というのは、どのような状態/状況を基にどのように判断したのでしょう？ それらについてこちらのヘルプ記事を参考に追記してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 例えばJavaプログラムの代わりに起動できたことの記録や渡されたパラメータ、作業ディレクトリなどを表示してpauseで確認待ちをするか、それらをファイルに出力するバッチファイルを作成して呼び出し、実行できているか・その時の状態は何かといったことを確認してみてはどうでしょう？ それが出来てから同様の状態でJavaプログラムに差し替えてみれば違いが分かるかもしれません。

Comment: 実行可能Jarを作る方法って話であればmaven assembly plugin つかってさくっとつくるのが悩みが少ないとおもうお

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最も簡単な方法を紹介します。

ファイル名をTest.javaとして以下のコードを保存してください。

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

上記のJavaコードは、以下のコマンドで、コマンドラインから実行することができました。

```
java Test.java
(もしくは)
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe" Test.java
```

エクセルVBAのjavaCommand変数に、
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe" Test.java
を指定して、動作するか確認できないでしょうか。

複雑さが増し、上記の方法では、管理しきれなくなってきたら、
コンパイルして.classファイルを利用してもよいですし、
マニフェストファイルや.jarアーカイブファイルを利用していくことを、
検討していけばよいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
コマンドラインからの実行も成功しました。
助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

> 調べるとjarに対して、マニフェストファイルへの記載が必要？とのことなのですが、
> ここでは、jar -xvf Sample.jarで解凍したマニフェストファイルに Main-Class: Sample を記載して、もう一度圧縮すればいいのでしょうか？

はい、そうです。マニュフェストファイルを作成/変更して、もう一度圧縮します。
マニュフェストを作成する場合は、

```
Main-Class: Sample
```

ではなく、メイン関数のあるクラスをフルパス(パッケージ名を含めたクラス名)で指定します。
例）Main-Class: com.example.app.MainAppなど

```
Main-Class: SqlFormatter
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ご指摘いただいた通り、指定の仕方が間違っていました。